# Selecting XML Elements for output in Thymeleaf

Tags: xml, thymeleaf

### If I had a structure like this:

```
<tag>
<item name="groot" group="a"/>
<item name="starlord" group="a"/>
<item name="rocket" group="a"/>

<item name="thanos" group="b"/>
<item name="ronan" group="b"/>
<item name="ego" group="b"/>
</tag>
```

### how could I make a template to select either a or b items by matching a variable?

#### example: selecting "group=a" because the variable is set to `a`

```
<tag>
<item name="groot" group="a"/>
<item name="starlord" group="a"/>
<item name="rocket" group="a"/>
</tag>
```

### Question

Is it possible also to eliminate all the "group=*" attributes as well since they are only needed for use in the template?

#### example

```
<item name="groot"/>
<item name="starlord/>
<item name="rocket"/>
```

### alternatives?

I'm new to Thymeleaf so any other suggestions to this problem are appreciated. In a normal templating engine I would enclose the grouped items within "a" and "b" blocks using instructions within comments and completely eliminate the group attributes, but my understanding is that ThymeLeaf doesn't allow processing inside of comments.

The attributes don't specifically need to be called "group", the main thing it is just something in the template to identify the group. If there is a more appropriate thymeleaf attribute then that is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [`th:if`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless) or, if you have multiple cases, [`th:switch`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#switch-statements).
Short example:

```
<tag th:if="${obj.someCondition}">
    <item name="groot"/>
</tag>

<tag th:if="${not obj.someCondition}">
    <item name="thanos"/>
</tag>
```

where `obj` is an object that you registered to Thymeleaf [`Context`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/2.0.2/org/thymeleaf/context/Context.html) (can't find the apidoc for 3.0 at the moment)

Comment: I think I understand, the whole `<tag/>` won't be written if it is not needed. I guess this library really makes more sense for HTML than XML. It seems it is really not well suited for XML that use schema.This would produce way too many errors in the template XML (if I'm doing this kind of thing in multiple places) - probably a templating engine that lets you add commands in comments would be better suited for my needs

Comment: @ycomp yep, it is HTML oriented. And yes, thymeleaf does process also comment blocks, see here: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#thymeleaf-prototype-only-comment-blocks ;-)